# How to subtract each Country's value by year

Tags: r

I have data for each Country's happiness (https://www.kaggle.com/unsdsn/world-happiness), and I made data for each year of the reports. Now, I don't know how to get the values for each year subtracted from each other e.g. how did happiness rank change from 2015 to 2017/2016 to 2017? I'd like to make a new df of differences for each.

I was able to bind the tables for columns in common and started to work on removing Countries that don't have data for all 3 years. I'm not sure if I'm going down a complicated path.

```
keepcols <- c("Country","Happiness.Rank","Economy..GDP.per.Capita.","Family","Health..Life.Expectancy.","Freedom","Trust..Government.Corruption.","Generosity","Dystopia.Residual","Year")
mydata2015 = read.csv("C:\\Users\\mmcgown\\Downloads\\2015.csv")
mydata2015$Year <- "2015"
data2015 <- subset(mydata2015, select = keepcols )
mydata2016 = read.csv("C:\\Users\\mmcgown\\Downloads\\2016.csv")
mydata2016$Year <- "2016"
data2016 <- subset(mydata2016, select = keepcols ) 
mydata2017 = read.csv("C:\\Users\\mmcgown\\Downloads\\2017.csv")
mydata2017$Year <- "2017"
data2017 <- subset(mydata2017, select = keepcols ) 
df <- rbind(data2015,data2016,data2017)
head(df, n=10)
tail(df, n=10)

df15 <- df[df['Year']=='2015',]
df16 <- df[df['Year']=='2016',]
df17 <- df[df['Year']=='2017',]
nocon <- rbind(setdiff(unique(df16['Country']),unique(df17['Country'])),setdiff(unique(df15['Country']),unique(df16['Country'])))
```

Don't have a clear path to accomplish what I want but it would look like

```
df16_to_17
Country   Happiness.Rank  ...(other columns)
Yemen     (Yemen[Happiness Rank in 2017] - Yemen[Happiness Rank in 2016])
USA       (USA[Happiness Rank in 2017] - USA[Happiness Rank in 2016])
(other countries)

df15_to_16
Country   Happiness.Rank  ...(other columns)
Yemen     (Yemen[Happiness Rank in 2016] - Yemen[Happiness Rank in 2015])
USA       (USA[Happiness Rank in 2016] - USA[Happiness Rank in 2015])
(other countries)
```

Comment: It's best practice to include a sample of the data you're working with, instead of a link to an external site which might require a separate login or which might not always be available. For example, could please you add the output of `dput(head(mydata2015))` in the body of your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's very straightforward with dplyr, and involves grouping by country and then finding the differences between consecutive values with base R's `diff`. Just make sure to use `df` and not `df15`, etc.:

```r
library(dplyr)

rank_diff_df <- df %>% 
    group_by(Country) %>% 
    mutate(Rank.Diff = c(NA, diff(Happiness.Rank)))
```

The above assumes that the data are arranged by year, which they are in your case because of the way you combined the dataframes. If not, you'll need to call `arrange(Year)` before the call to `mutate`. Filtering out countries with missing year data isn't necessary, but can be done after `group_by()` with `filter(n() == 3)`.

If you would like to view the differences it would make sense to drop some variables and rearrange the data:

```r
rank_diff_df %>% 
    select(Year, Country, Happiness.Rank, Rank.Diff) %>% 
    arrange(Country)
```

Which returns:

```r
# A tibble: 470 x 4
# Groups:   Country [166]
   Year  Country     Happiness.Rank Rank.Diff
   <chr> <fct>                <int>     <int>
 1 2015  Afghanistan            153        NA
 2 2016  Afghanistan            154         1
 3 2017  Afghanistan            141       -13
 4 2015  Albania                 95        NA
 5 2016  Albania                109        14
 6 2017  Albania                109         0
 7 2015  Algeria                 68        NA
 8 2016  Algeria                 38       -30
 9 2017  Algeria                 53        15
10 2015  Angola                 137        NA
# … with 460 more rows
```

The above data frame will work well with ggplot2 if you are planning on plotting the results.

If you don't feel comfortable with dplyr you can use base R's `merge` to combine the dataframes, and then create a new dataframe with the differences as columns:

```r
df_wide <- merge(merge(df15, df16, by = "Country"), df17, by = "Country")

rank_diff_df <- data.frame(Country = df_wide$Country,
                           Y2015.2016 = df_wide$Happiness.Rank.y -
                               df_wide$Happiness.Rank.x,
                           Y2016.2017 = df_wide$Happiness.Rank -
                               df_wide$Happiness.Rank.y
                           )
```

Which returns:

```r
head(rank_diff_df, 10)

       Country Y2015.2016 Y2016.2017
1  Afghanistan          1        -13
2      Albania         14          0
3      Algeria        -30         15
4       Angola          4         -1
5    Argentina         -4         -2
6      Armenia         -6          0
7    Australia         -1          1
8      Austria         -1          1
9   Azerbaijan          1          4
10     Bahrain         -7         -1
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the three datasets are present in your environment with the name `data2015`, `data2016` and `data2017`, we can add a `year` column with the respective year and keep the columns which are present in `keepcols` vector. `arrange` the data by `Country` and `Year`, `group_by` `Country`, keep only those countries which are present in all 3 years and then subtract the values from previous rows using `lag` or `diff`.

```
library(dplyr)

data2015$Year <- 2015
data2016$Year <- 2016
data2017$Year <- 2017
df <- bind_rows(data2015, data2016, data2017)
data <- df[keepcols]

data %>%
  arrange(Country, Year) %>% 
  group_by(Country) %>%
  filter(n() == 3) %>%
  mutate_at(-1, ~. - lag(.)) #OR
  #mutate_at(-1, ~c(NA, diff(.)))

# A tibble: 438 x 10
# Groups:   Country [146]
#   Country Happiness.Rank Economy..GDP.pe… Family Health..Life.Ex… Freedom
#   <chr>            <int>            <dbl>  <dbl>            <dbl>   <dbl>
# 1 Afghan…             NA          NA      NA            NA        NA     
# 2 Afghan…              1           0.0624 -0.192        -0.130    -0.0698
# 3 Afghan…            -13           0.0192  0.471         0.00731  -0.0581
# 4 Albania             NA          NA      NA            NA        NA     
# 5 Albania             14           0.0766 -0.303        -0.0832   -0.0387
# 6 Albania              0           0.0409  0.302         0.00109   0.0628
# 7 Algeria             NA          NA      NA            NA        NA     
# 8 Algeria            -30           0.113  -0.245         0.00038  -0.0757
# 9 Algeria             15           0.0392  0.313        -0.000455  0.0233
#10 Angola              NA          NA      NA            NA        NA     
# … with 428 more rows, and 4 more variables: Trust..Government.Corruption. <dbl>,
#   Generosity <dbl>, Dystopia.Residual <dbl>, Year <dbl>
```

The value of first row for each `Year` would always be `NA`, rest of the values would be subtracted by it's previous values.